# Save canvas as image in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a javascript canvas blob image to my controller method in ASP.NET Core 2.1. but my string parameters is always `null` in method.

This is my **JavaScript:**

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',
        data: { imageData: image },
        ajaxasync: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Image saved successfully !');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my **Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public  JsonResult Add(string imageData)
{
    try
    {
        var folderName = @"uploads/";
        var webRootPath = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
        string fileNameWitPath = newPath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult("Success");
        }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return new JsonResult("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove this line

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

The reason is JQuery transforms object passed as `data` param to `key1=value1&key2=value2&...` format by default which apparently is not valid json. So you do not need to specify `application/json` content type and ASP.NET Core will automatically parse this data properly.

But if you want to make the request work with `json` content type you will need to do the following

**JavaScript**

```
var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
var data = JSON.stringify({ imageData: image }); //serializing object to json

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Home")',
    data: data, //passing json string
    ajaxasync: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
    }
});
```

**C#**

```
public class Model
{
    public string ImageData { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody]Model model) { //..
```